# Where is it possible to download trial of Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Where is it possible to download trial of Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2005?
Microsoft is not offering it in Download section anymore.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2005 TFS trial is available to MSDN Subscribers. I don't believe it is generally available anymore, now that Visual Studio 2008 TFS is out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already implemented TFS, then you should look at TFS 2008.  It is much improved and a VS 2005 client can connect to it just fine.  To download an 90-day trial version of TFS 2008 visit the following link:

[http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b0155166-b0a3-436e-ac95-37d7e39a440c](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b0155166-b0a3-436e-ac95-37d7e39a440c&displaylang=en)

If you just wanted to play with TFS and Team System, then I would encourage you to download the pre-configured Virtual PC image as it will save you the time of installing the pre-requisites required for a full TFS installation.  You can get the VPC here which will run until the end of the calendar year:

[http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72262ead-e49d-43d4-aa45-1da2a27d9a65](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72262ead-e49d-43d4-aa45-1da2a27d9a65&displaylang=en)

Is there any reason why you wanted TFS 2005 rather than the latest version?

Comment: Hi Martin,

thank you for your answer. I know about TFS 2008. I understand my request is not typicall. The reason is cusomer is using this edition and is not able to upgrade (whatever why).

Ayyway, thank you both!